# Is this picture correct from the point of view of physics?

Tags: fluid-statics

[image]

This picture violates some laws of physics. Am I right?

Comment: Which one, do you supppose?

Comment: whater pressure on the left side of burrow does not equal to whater pressure on the right side, but it looks like it does

Comment: The picture looks fine to me. I don't understand why you say: *water pressure on the left side of burrow does not equal to water pressure on the right side*. Do you mean that the outside entrances are at different depths?

Comment: @user102417:   Are you being confused by the water line to the left of the dam where the lake meets the trees?  This is far off in the distance and not at a higher elevation.

Answer (score 3):

Your picture is perfectly consistent with the laws of physics, and in particular with the principle of hydrostatic equilibrium, which demands that the pressure at each point be only a function of the height. All the water surfaces, at the dashed line,

[image]

are at the same height and therefore at the same pressure.

The depths of the burrows do not matter: it is true that the entrance to the burrow on the left is at a higher pressure and the water is pushing into the burrow harder than on the right, but the left burrow has a taller water column with which to balance that force. Everything works out nicely to an equilibrium of forces, and there will be no water flow.